# I am getting a Segmentation fault in merge sort program

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Please can you point out how i can correct this segmentation fault error. Here i am taking an array n trying to sort array.i have attached the program below. I am unable to find the error in my program.
If u do find the error please do tell me the best possible way to debug such recursive functions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
/*****************mergesort program******************************/
int merge(int arr[],int l, int m,int r){
int i , j, k;
int n1 = m - l + 1;
int n2 = r - m;
int L[n1],R[n2];

for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
  L[i]=arr[l+i];
for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
  R[j]=arr[m+1+j];

i=0;
j=0;
k=l;
while(i < n1 && j < n2)
{ 
  if(L[i] <= R[j])
  {
    arr[k]=L[i];
    i++;
  }
  else{
    arr[k]=R[j];
    j++;
  }
  k++;
}

while(i < n1){
  arr[k]=L[i];
  i++;
  k++;
}

while(j < n2){
  arr[k]=R[j];
  j++;
  k++;
}
}

void mergesort(int arr[],int l,int r){

if(l < r)
{
  int m = l + (r - 1) / 2;

  mergesort(arr,l,m);
  mergesort(arr,m+1,r);


  merge(arr, l, m, r);
}
}

void printarray(int arr[],int size){
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}

int main(){
  int A[]={4,5,7,2,1,3};
  int n=sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
  printarray(A,n);
  mergesort(A,0,n-1);
  printarray(A,n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int m = l + (r - 1) / 2;`looks suspicious. Why not `int m = l + (r - l) / 2;` instead. With such a `m`, you get out-of-bound access. Generally (on linux), a tool like `valgrind` allows to easily find where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you @Damien.That solves my issue.I cant believe it was soo simple.You have my thanks.

Comment: There are many debugging techniques.  Most are more effective in some situations than in others.  For something like this, among the things you could try would be (1) reducing the problem to a [mre] and (2) either printing key data at various points so that you can see where and how it goes wrong, or running the code in a debugger for the same purpose.

Comment: Style comment: Your spacing is woefully erratic, which makes it harder to read your code.  You don't indent consistently.  Sometimes you put spaces after commas; sometimes you don't.  Sometimes you put spaces before commas; sometimes you don't.  Get into a habit of consistency, preferably with no spaces before commas and one space after commas, with only occasional deviations.  Learn to use `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { … }` when feasible.  Use spacing in expressions consistently.